# Sorting an array of objects in javascript by key value does not work

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I am trying to sort and array of objects in javascript that represent interfaces of devices. I have found some code here that seems to work for some cases and does not for others.

So here is my code:

```
compareByName = function(a, b) {
    console.log("sort by name");
    const nameA = a.name.toUpperCase();
    const nameB = b.name.toUpperCase();

    let comparison = 0;
    if (nameA > nameB) {
        comparison = 0;
    } else if (nameA < nameB) {
        comparison = -1;
    }
    return comparison;
}

vm.interfaceData.sort(compareByName);
```

It works when i have objects like this:

```
[
 {
   "name": "eth4",
 },
 {
   "name": "eth3",
 },
 {
   "name": "eth2",
 },
 {
   "name": "eth2",
 }
]

eth0
eth1
eth2
eth3
```

But when i have names like this it seems not to work anymore:

```
[
  {
   "name": "GigabitEthernet0/8",
  },
  {
   "name": "SBB",
  },
  {
   "name": "SR-2",
  },
  {
   "name": "GigabitEthernet0/7",
  },
  {
   "name": "SR-1",
  },
  {
   "name": "GigabitEthernet0/5",
  },
  {
   "name": "GigabitEthernet0/4",
  }
]

GigabitEthernet0/8          
SBB         
SR-2        
GigabitEthernet0/7          
SR-1        
GigabitEthernet0/5          
GigabitEthernet0/4
```

Comment: um, should be a 1 and not a zero if greater....

Answer (score 2):

It should be `comparison = 1;` wnen `nameA > nameB`.

Or perhaps better, use [`.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

```
return nameA.localeCompare(nameB);
```

---

```js
const vm = {
  interfaceData: [{
      "name": "GigabitEthernet0/8",
    },
    {
      "name": "SBB",
    },
    {
      "name": "SR-2",
    },
    {
      "name": "GigabitEthernet0/7",
    },
    {
      "name": "SR-1",
    },
    {
      "name": "GigabitEthernet0/5",
    },
    {
      "name": "GigabitEthernet0/4",
    }
  ]
};

console.log(vm.interfaceData.sort(compareByName));

function compareByName(a, b) {
  return a.name.toUpperCase().localeCompare(b.name.toUpperCase());
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thx! And really nice short code, i like it.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison is inaccurate.

This :

```
if (nameA > nameB) {
    comparison = 0;
}
```

should be

```
if (nameA > nameB) {
    comparison = 1;
}
```

You may also use [String.localCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/localeCompare) function :

```
const nameA = a.name.toUpperCase();
const nameB = b.name.toUpperCase();
return a.localeCompare(b);
```